# Transition Table for Knuth-Morris-Prat

Tags: algorithm, search

I'm going through the KMP algorithm and in this slide a powerpoint I downloaded it shows a transition table made from the fail array for the algorithm.  I cannot made heads or tails of it.  What exactly is this transition table showing in relation to the DFM? The transition table is in the upper right.

[image: slide]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transition table describes *all* the transitions in the state machine: the left hand column gives the ID of the source state, the middle column gives the value that causes a transition from the source state to the target state, and the right hand column gives the ID of the target state. In contrast, the graphs and left hand table only show a subset of the transitions.

I think there's at least one erroneous entry though; either the left hand table or the right hand table is wrong about what State 1 should map to when an 'a' is encountered. Couldn't tell you which for sure though without seeing the rest of the slides.